# Django DRF websocket channels 2 and authorize with token from Simple JWT

Tags: websocket, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a simple chat and I use channels 2. I have a problem with authorize via token JWT (Simple JWT) before user will be connect in consumer.

**My middleware:**

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser


class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        headers = dict(scope['headers'])
        if b'authorization' in headers:
            try:
                token_name, token_key = headers[b'authorization'].decode().split()
                if token_name == 'Token':
                    token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
                    scope['user'] = token.user
            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
        return self.inner(scope)

TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

**Snippet from my consumer:**

```
User = get_user_model()


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        """
        Join channel group by chatname.
        """
        self.group_name = 'chat_{0}'.format(self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['chatname'])

        if self.scope['user'] == AnonymousUser():
            raise DenyConnection("Invalid User")

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        """
        Leave channel by group name.
        """
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

**My routing:**

```
from .auth import TokenAuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path('ws/chat/<slug:chatname>/', ChatConsumer),
        ])
    ),
})
```

Now are two question.

How pass token in my test client web socket?
And that above snippet are properly? Because i receive from client

```
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 403
```

**My test client:**

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
test_json = "some test to send via socket"
def test_url2(url):
    async def inner():
        async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(test_json)
            print(test_json)
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(inner())

test_url2("ws://0.0.0.0:8080/ws/over/3ff621b1-b392-4a82-ab35-a0ad81ab1179_f99c82ba-1404-442c-ba08-653f84d58aa4")
```

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to so, as a work around I accessed the user from the request object. to set up middleware that's going to give you the request object:

```
#get_request.py
from threading import current_thread

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


_requests = {}


def current_request():
    return _requests.get(current_thread().ident, None)


class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread().ident] = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # when response is ready, request should be flushed
        _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # if an exception has happened, request should be flushed too
        _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
```

In your settings.py add to the existing MIDDLEWARE list:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ... 
    'users.get_request.RequestMiddleware',
   ...
]
```

Finally to get the user: (in your consumers.py or anywhere)

```
from users.get_request import current_request

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.user = current_request().user
```